# Sensitive electrical flow switch for 1-1/4" plastic pipe

Tags: switches, water, fluid-pump

As part of a water-treatment system without a holding tank, a chlorine pump is installed on a 1-1/4" water LDPE pipe. To test for flow, a section of the pipe was replaced with 2" PVC, and in this section, a paddle type flow switch was installed, of this sort:

[image: picture of paddle flow switch]

Here is a sketch of the installation, for clarity. The supply pipe is 1,1/4" (+/- 32mm) diameter LDPE pipe. In the section of larger diameter pipe, the switch assembly and injection assembly are installed. Then the out-flow pipe is reduced again to 1-1/4".

[image: flow switch installation sketch]

However, the [manual for this particular model](https://pim.genebre.es/genebre/documents/fichas_tecnicas/2850.pdf) specifies a minimum flow of 3200 lt/hr in a 2" pipe, and the actual use in this case is far less, usually in the range of 360-1800 lt/hr. Even if I install a "bottle neck" down to 1" (which is the minimum diameter for this model of flow switch), the switch catalogue specifies a flow of 1100 lt/hr to close the switch, which is still outside of the low range that I need to detect.

So I went to the online search engines to find what "flow switch" and "flow sensor" options are common, and among the options I found ultrasonic flow sensors and turbine flow sensors. The turbine flow sensors provide a PWM output, and I don't know what circuitry I may need to operate a mains voltage relay from it. The ultrasonic flow sensors are attractive because they are non-invasive, and seem ideal for plastic pipes; but it seems that they need quite a bit of supporting electronics to do the Doppler math, and this is too much for what I need, since we only need an "on/off" switch telling us that there is flow--I don't need to know *how much* water is flowing, only that it is above the 6 l/min flow, which means that one of the taps is open.

1. What kind of flow switch is good for this scenario? or
2. What kind of circuitry would I need to use a PWM signal from a turbine sensor to operate a mains voltage relay?

Frame challenges welcome.

Comment: Later, I'll try to add a photograph of a home-baked solution that I have begun to make.

Comment: Hello and welcome.  May I suggest you look at major distributors in your region, where you will find flow switches, pretty much exactly like the one you have, but look for a model with a flow switching rating that suits your requirements.  They come with all kinds of ratings.  The one I was just looking at had an adjustable setting between 1 and 10 litre/min.

Comment: When looking at ultrasonic sensors you should be looking at "smart" sensors with all the doppler math built-in, not raw/dumb sensors which you have to signal-process yourself.

Comment: How are you adjusting your chlorine dose?  wouldn't it help to have a flow *transmitter* and a control loop to pace the chlorine metering pump?

Comment: @Theodore The chlorine dose isn't adjusted proportionally to flow; it's just injected with a dosage pump (a small plastic reciprocating syringe type of machine) which runs when the flow is detected as "on". Since the water flow rate is usually inside of a small enough range, the chlorine is supposedly kept inside of its allowed range of ppm, too. I would have liked a control loop, but this was already installed, and I'm thinking about the options to restore as-is, before re-working the whole system, which I would do if the first option fails to keep the chlorine levels in range.

Comment: RE: control loop, just so I understand, I'm imagining (in the concrete) something like a turbine style of flow meter, then some sort of microprocessor to "understand" the data from it, do the proportion math and control the pump, with perhaps feedback from a post-injection chlorine level meter?

Comment: A search of the Grainger online catalog shows several flow switches with the correct 1-1/4” pipe size and flows in your stated range. Why complicate things beyond that?

Comment: @MarkLeavitt Mainly because I live in Chile, and there is no Grainger close enough to conveniently send me stuff. :) Also, the boss wanted a different system, since the paddle switch didn't work. There are other distributors, though, and I may be able to talk him into using something like you suggest.

Comment: I was thinking of a Chlorine metering pump like this one: [Pulsafeeder MP](https://www.evoqua.com/en/evoqua/parts--consumables/chemicals-chemical-feeders-and-parts/chemical-feeders/solenoid-chemical-pumps/4-20-ma-controlled-pumps/pulsafeeder-mp-series-lmb4-metering-pump-lmb4ta-vtc1-500/) with its own controls.  The control signal comes from a flow transmitter with a standard 4-20 mA analog output.  (This model may be more than you need, but it illustrates the idea.)  It can also use a pulse input rather than analog.